# Which kernel was used for developing the GNU tools before Linux?

Tags: kernel

I'm guessing that when the GNU project started in the 1980s, the tools were developed in the environment of a Unix operating system, including some proprietary kernel? I'm asking this purely out of historical curiosity (I've been reading up on the topic but couldn't find an answer to this specific point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, GNU used Unix kernel. They started to develop own kernel named "GNU Hurd" in 1990, but it did not become as popular as Linux.

Comment: I guess that's quite obvious now that I think about it.